# Stopping and fixing a FireBase hack

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

My Android has been hacked with FireBase technology. Can someone point me in the right direction of discovery so I may take control of my Android again. Thank you.

Comment: are you sure of this that your android has been hacked with firebase technology ? Try to avoid from asking these question.

Comment: Im sure. Im obviously causing sum disturbances because at times im able to see whats being logged and sent else where. My phone has been rooted but so well that it fools its self into thinking its not. fooling around with certain apps from the pkay store show me new things all the time. how can i stop this? I admit im no computer wiz to this degree. Sdk cards were used as well.